# PHP pre-defined function - count - returns a strange (to me) value in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php

I started learning PHP from a book and I got a list of useful PHP commands(sort, count, is_array ect.)

I tried using count() but it seems tricky to me.

count($chessboard, 0) outputs 8 and that's fine I think (because it has 8 rows, I get it) but when I use count($chessboard, 1) it outputs 72 and I don't get why.

In my opinion I think it should output 64 (because 8 rows * 8 columns or 8 rows * 8 elements per row).

Why does it output 64?

```html
<?php
$chessboard = array(
    array('r', 'n', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'b', 'n', 'r'),
    array('p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'),
    array(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '),
    array(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '),
    array(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '),
    array(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '),
    array('P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P'),
    array('R', 'N', 'B', 'Q', 'K', 'B', 'N', 'R')
  );
  
echo count($chessboard, 1);
```

Comment: For better readability of the code, I recommend using the PHP constant `COUNT_RECURSIVE` instead of `1` as second parameter. This makes the behavior of `count()` a lot more obvious when you come back to this part of your code later.

Comment: @Namoshek thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `1` as the second parameter to `count()`, it counts recursively - so for the first level it counts 8 items (meaning 8 sub-arrays) and then proceeds to second level, where it encounters 8 items in each sub-array. Thus 8 + 8 * 8 = 72.

Comment: Thanks! Now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

You have inserted multiple arrays inside an array and passed the mode '1' to `count()` . This makes it count recursively and it starts counting the sub arrays inside the main array which has 8 sub arrays in your case. So 8 is the number of count for the first case i.e. main array has 8 sub arrays. Then it starts counting recursively another 8 subarrays which gives u a total 64. So here, 64+8=72. Hope it helps.

Comment: It does. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. Glad, You understood.